# What are Frequecny differences in SPI Flash

Tags: frequency

Does 81Hz make a difference from one SPI flash (500KHz) to another SPI flash(419KHz? If so, what is the impact?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: `difference` in what?

Comment: Down vote for poorly specified question.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Ask a clear question, show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with any schematic. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: You people are rude.... Its funny how people hide behind their screens. Down vote that

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is to be found in the data sheets for the various SPI Flash devices you are asking about and in the data sheet for the host side SPI controller.

You need to inherently understand the signal handshake protocol between the host controller and the SPI flash device and the associate timing requirements and timing responses for each end of the interface.

Working through the timing and understanding it will provide the key to the maximum frequencies that may be possible to any given device. As a matter of fact detailed timing analysis like this is essential for any electronics design that you engage in. It is one of the fundamental activities needed to ensure a reliable design.